# Get the average within a specific range

Tags: mysql, sql

To get started, I have a database based on sports betting. I have one table called 'MATCHES' (id_match / sport_id / League_id /team / quota / result ).

Imagine that we have the following values ​​in the table:

```
id_match | sport_id | League_id | team | quota | result
---------------------------------------------------------
   1     |    x     |  xx       | xx   |  1.4  |  W
---------------------------------------------------------
   2     |    x     |  xx       | xx   |  2.4  |  W
---------------------------------------------------------
   3     |    x     |  xx       | xx   |  2.2  |  L
---------------------------------------------------------
   4     |    x     |  xx       | xx   |  2.35 |  W
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the percentage of success of the quotas grouped by a specific range, so the query that I am using is the following:

```
SELECT  AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 1.01 and 1.24 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '1 - 1.25' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 1.25 and 1.49 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '1.25 - 1.50' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 1.50 and 1.74 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '1.50 - 1.75' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 1.75 and 1.99 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '1.75 - 2' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 2 and 2.49 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '2 - 2.50' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 2.5 and 2.99 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '2.50 - 3' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota BETWEEN 3 and 4 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '3 - 4' ,
    AVG(IF(bet_matches.quota >3.99 and bet_matches.result='W', 100, 0)) as '4 - x' 
FROM bet_matches
```

The problem comes when the winrate of the quotas is not adequately reflected in the results. The winrate of each range does not appear correctly. These are the results i am generating:

```
1 - 1.5 | 2 - 2.5 | 
-------------------
  25%   |   50%
```

And these are the results i want to obtain:

```
 1 - 1.5 | 2 - 2.5 | 
-------------------
  100%   |   66%
```

Any idea how to obtain this results? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT  AVG( CASE WHEN bet_matches.quota NOT BETWEEN 1.01 and 1.24 THEN NULL
                  WHEN bet_matches.result = 'W' THEN 100.0
                  ELSE 0
             END) as `1 - 1.25`,
        AVG( CASE WHEN bet_matches.quota NOT BETWEEN 1.25 and 1.49 THEN NULL
                  WHEN bet_matches.result = 'W' THEN 100.0
                  ELSE 0
             END) as `11.25 - 1.50`,
      . . .
FROM bet_matches;
```

The key is that you are counting *all* rows for the average.  You just want to take the proportion based on the range condition.

Note that I replaced `IF()` with the standard `CASE`.  And use backticks for the column names.  Do not use single quotes for identifiers.  They are easily confused with strings.